# Interpolate a countably infinite number of points within a bounded region?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, lagrange-interpolation

Suppose I have $x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers, and let $|x|$ be the length of $x$ when expressed in binary. I wish to find an analytic function of $x$ which interpolates the points $(x,|x|)$.

Is this possible, and if so is this function computable? Since $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\cap [0,1]$ is a countable number of points it seems to satisfy some of the necessary properties for this scheme.

Comment: $|x| = \infty$ unless $x$ is a **rational** number whose denominator in reduced for is $2^n5^m$ for some $n,m$ (in which case $|x| = \max \{m, n\}$).

Comment: Have changed x to be rational rather than algebraic.

Comment: That doesn't change matters. You are still requiring a function $f(x)$ which is actually $= \infty$ on a dense subset of the points of $[0,1]$. An analytic function is never $=\infty$. Meromorphic functions (analytic except for poles) can be considered to $=\infty$ at the poles, but their poles are isolated, not dense.

Comment: Forgive my naive physicist's understanding: surely $x$ here is unbounded, but not actually infinite? Or is that what "$=\infty$" means in this context?

Comment: I said $|x| = \infty$, because that is exactly what I meant. "Unbounded" is a meaningless term for a single number. If $x = \dfrac p{2^n}$ for some integers $p$ and $n$, then the "length" of the binary expression for $x$ is $n$ (I was thinking of decimals in my previous comment, which is why I included a power of $5$ in the denominator there). For ALL other numbers, the binary expression *does not terminate*, and therefore is infinite in length. So $|x|$ is not "unbounded". It is $\infty$. Nothing less.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!